# Has Catwoman been to the Batcave before New 52?

Tags: dc, batman, catwoman

I ran [into this blog post](http://comicnewbies.com/2014/10/05/batman-brings-catwoman-to-the-batcave/) about "Forever Evil #4", which shows Selena in the Batcave, with a 1-line text "This would be the first time Batman brought Catwoman to the Batcave **in the New 52 timeline**".

Does that mean that Catwoman has been inside the Batcave **prior to the New 52**?

I'm only interested in similar situations to the one in the issue being reviewed:

- Catwoman is conscious
- She is aware that she's in the Batcave
- Comics only (no films, animated series or games).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes, a frankly astonishing number of times

- A screencap from 1983's *Detective Comics* #526 indicates that Catwoman managed to get into the Batcave to have a catfight<sup>1</sup> with Talia:

  [image]

  She comes back a couple more times in the course of that issue, and the ease with which she gets in suggests that she'd been there before
- In "The Stalking", a text story by Grant Morrison published in *Batman UK Annual* 1986, Catwoman again manages to sneak into the cave. Obviously Batman didn't really invest in a decent security system until the 90s
- Batman invites her in 2002's *Batman: Hush*, which is also the story arc where Batman reveals his secret identity to Catwoman:

  [image]
- She was down there a couple of times in the *JLA: Crisis of Conscience* storyline, published in 2005
- I found the following screenshot online, which appears to depict Batman and Catwoman in the Batcave together, but I don't know what issue it's from; since Batman isn't wearing his cowl, it's presumably either elswhere in the multiverse (Earth-2, maybe?) or post-*Hush*

  [image]
- While it's arguable whether this is post-New 52 or not, she was also brought to the Batcave in *Batman '66* #1 (2013), though she was unconscious for the trip:

  [image]

---

<sup>1</sup> **Cat**fight, lol

Comment: ^_^ I love the implication in the last panel that Robin was sharing one lap or another in the car.

Comment: Considering that Catwoman is the closest thing to a girlfriend that's also a peer of sorts, I am not surprised.

Comment: @Escoce Considering he's letting his on-again-off-again frenemy sneak into the place where he keeps all of his potentially life-saving toys, which happens to sit under a glut of blackmail material, I'm more than slightly surprised

Comment: @Excoce Talia is also in that category